# PyCharm - Trust location not working on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm clicking multiple times in **Trust Project** in my computer (MacBook Pro 2021 with Mac OS X Monterey) to trust Python projects in PyCharm, but does not produces any effect , what should I do ?

[image]

Comment: Please go to Preferences, type "trusted" in the search box and locate `Trusted Locations` settings page. Add the path to this project there (if it;s not there yet). Then try restarting the IDE. Any better now? In any case: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283747 2) Or could this be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284642 ?

Comment: P.S. Found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-287097 -- looks like yours.

Comment: Yes, this is mine. I tried to do what they suggested and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I also created an issue at Jetbrains's forum and I followed and it was suggested (clean the trusted_paths.xml file) and it worked

[Question at Jetbrains's forum](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-287097#focus=Comments-27-5713492.0-0)